# getting an error while setting up firebase

Tags: firebase, gradle

while i was connecting firebase to my flutter project on android studio iam getting this error i have done all the setup they mentioned in the firebase installation section

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because, there is no repositories list in buildscript{}.

You can solve this issue by copying the repositories list from allprojects{} and paste it in buildscript{}.

Here's how you can solve this issue,

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

Comment: i did that but still getting the same error

Comment: buildscript{
    repositories{
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}